# Multiple views on a view area

Tags: wpf, view

I'm building a application with the WPF but i'm novice with WPF.

I would like tips about how make an application(desktop application) that swapping the views at a unique window. My preference is to code separately each view and using them as  dynamic content  in the main window. As instance of content swapping, the msn messenger, from the login to the contact list screen.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  use the concept of Frames for the intended functionality , if that can be an option you are looking.

You can refer the below link for the same.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#Frame_in_Standalone_Applications

(Please mark as answered , if it solves your problem.)